# Как pdf документ отобразить на PyGTK?

Tags: python, pdf, sqlite, pygtk, sql

Имеется электронный документ pdf. Как вывести этот документ на монитор (как ридеры например). И еще как можно выдергивать слова из pdf и собрать в базу SQLite

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй эти библиотеки , без них увы не получится

[Pypdf](http://www.pybrary.net/pyPdf/)

[ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/)